# List GCR private registry images

Tags: image, list, private, google-container-registry

I need to list the images that are stored in each registry. I have the user **auth details**, but I don't have the **registry names**. I need to list **all the registries and the images located in each registry**. Can I able to do it via **Google Storage APIs**?

I tried via **Docker v2 APIs**. **Docker search** is the only possible way, but I need to know the **respective registry name** for searching. I don't have those details. So I need another possible way to do it. Also i need to list the tags in each repo.

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of the registry domains [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/#pushing_to_the_registry).

For `project-id` based repositories they are essentially: `{us,eu,asia}.gcr.io` and `gcr.io`.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can do it by fetching the image metadata from Google Storage based on the region. Bucket name will be **artifacts.projectID.appspot.com**