# Retrieve a list of all container's images registered in Container Engine Registry

Tags: docker-registry, gcloud-cli

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all container's images registered in Container Engine Registry. The command that should do the job "gcloud docker images" brings me only local images. In spite of this "gcloud docker pull gcr.io/myproject/myname:tag" works as expected.

Also, I have used a search API but it retrieves me names of images without their tags:

```
gcloud docker search gcr.io/[myproject]
```

Has somebody an experience with it?

**Installed stuff:**

```
Google Cloud SDK 99.0.0
```

- alpha 2016.01.12
- beta 2016.01.12
- bq 2.0.18
- bq-nix 2.0.18
- core 2016.02.26
- core-nix 2016.02.05
- gcd-emulator v1beta3-1.0.0
- gcloud
- gsutil 4.17
- gsutil-nix 4.15
- kubectl
- kubectl-linux-x86_64 1.1.7

Comment: I have implemented this previously. I couldn't find any independent API to list the images in the google private registry. Can you please share the API that u used to retrieve the names of images from GCR. It will be useful to debug. You may get some idea from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193602/list-gcr-private-registry-images).

Comment: curl -u _token:$(gcloud auth print-access-token)   https://gcr.io/v2/<project>/<repository>/tags/list. This request brings to me a manifest of images and its tags. Only filtered by the repository.

Comment: I did the same thing when I implemented this with my back-end code. retrieving each repository and then getting tags from each repo. I couldn't find a proper API associated with google for this. Hope you will find one. Do share the fix if you find one.

Comment: Sorry. Press on "enter" by mistake. [This](https://gist.github.com/worroc/2aa1d6cbd0115f2f9c0cd098f56eb329) is an example code. It fetches all images and tags in one list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following command to get list of all the repositories in your GCP project

```
gcloud container images list --repository=HOST/PROJECT-ID
```

Here *HOST* would be *gcr.io* / *us.gcr.io* / *eu.gcr.io* etc based on your repo location

If you want to get list of all the versions of images in specific repository you can use *list-tags* command.

```
gcloud container images list-tags HOST/project-id/REPONAME
```